# If you are streaming a remote video and start to copy it locally, will it use the same bit steam for the copy

Tags: streaming

An mp4 video is on computer A.  From computer B, I open an smb://computerA connection, then start watching the mp4 video.  It's slow, so I decide to copy it while watching over the same smb connection (and launch it locally when finished), I access the mounted smb share and copy the file to my desktop.  Will the copy make use of the existing bit stream so it doesn't have to reread sections of the video, or will it start a completely unrelated copy regardless of the streaming connection?

This is on Mac OS X, but I'd be happy to hear an answer for Linux 2.x or 3.x

Comment: It's hard to know what your asking. I think the problem is asking about bit-stream. Try asking without using the words bitstream. Or try explaining why it matters if there is a new bit stream or not. Maybe that can help us answer better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a lot on the software in use (on both ends). Also your term "bit-stream" seems misleading.

Technically the answer is no. The position in the stream used for playback would not be "reusable" for file transfer. But that answer is no even on Mac.

What I think your asking is does the video file need to be read from disk or will is be in RAM. That is not an easy question to answer. Linux stores file caches in your free ram, of there is enough room then yes, the file transfer will actually transfer from RAM and not the disk. However it's a transparent process, and if there's not enough RAM, or if the file has been flushed from cache for some reason, then it would read from disk.

From a users perspective there should be no reason to care, the OS will do what it needs to transfer and to stream the file.

Comment: You're right, the question wasn't well thought out.  I think the question really should have been whether the cache would have served the content to the cp or whether it would have read from the remote filesystem again.  In this case, the file is ~500MB and I have 8GB of RAM and these are the only foreground operations.  I think it probably will be served from cache.